# Make python return something to the terminal

Tags: python

I wonder if you could help me with this question....

```
import os 
os.system("su")
```

At this point it will ask for a password, so I would like python to automatically return a password, could you help me in that case?

Comment: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: You may also be reinventing Fabric, see e.g. http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#how-do-i-use-su-to-run-commands-as-another-user .